# Improve speed with a double for loop

Tags: performance-tuning, procedural-programming

I am trying to calculate the Euclidean distance of pairs of points $(x_i,y_i)$ with $x$ and $y$ given as separate lists.

```
sqdiff = {};
For[i = 1, i < Length[x] - 1, i++,
 {
  For[j = i + 1, j < Length[x], j++,
   {
    AppendTo[sqdiff, (x[[i]] - x[[j]])^2 + (y[[i]] - y[[j]])^2];
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

Even for 800 points, this loops takes orders of magnitudes longer than an identical loop written in MATLAB. Are there any improvements I can make? Thanks.

Comment: "Are there any improvements I can make? ". 
Yes. Don't program Mathematica as if it were Matlab.
Use `DistanceMatrix`, vectorize it, etc.

Comment: Even in _MATLAB_ this were bad programming style. Typically, one is taught to use vectorization there as well. Due to the use of `For`/`for` and the to the successive `AppendTo` (`cat` in _MATLAB_).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even in *MATLAB*, this would not be good programming style because successive concatenation is awfully slow. (And `for` is slow, too.) Better use `Table`:

```
n = 800;
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];

Table[
 With[{xi = x[[i]], yi = y[[i]]},
  Table[
   (xi - x[[j]])^2 + (yi - y[[j]])^2
   , {j, 1, n}]
  ],
 {i, 1, n}
 ]
```

Better:

```
Table[
  Sqrt[(x[[i]] - x)^2 + (y[[i]] - y)^2],
  {i, 1, n}
  ];
```

Even better: Use `DistanceMatrix`:

```
DistanceMatrix[Transpose[{x, y}]];
```

Comment: 100% it is bad style, but it still was done in under 5 seconds in matlab with 500k points, so I was shocked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: With 500k? Impossible. That would make a $500k \times 500k$ matrix or an $(500k)^2$ vector. I doubt that your _MATLAB_ code is equivalent to this on.

Comment: 1000 random points -> ~ 500,000 distinct pairs iterated. Took a few seconds.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. The major point here is `AppendTo`, because it involves a copy operation of the full array. So your loop is actually of complexity $O(n^3)$.

Answer (score 8):

```
(Subtract @@@ Subsets[Most@x, {2}])^2 + (Subtract @@@Subsets[Most@y, {2}])^2
```

will produce precisely the output of your OP with appropriate performance. Since your output is a small subset of all-points distances, it should also outperform things like `DistanceMatrix`.

A comparison of OP and this up to 300 length for timing:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain some of the syntax in greater detail if you have time.